# css background-repeat

Tags: css, background-repeat

So i have this DIV with a background

this is the style:

```
#book{
    width: 800px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0px;
    font-family: love;
    font-size: 20px;
    background:url("../img/boek.png");
}
```

The problem that I have is that there is space between those two backgrounds, and I really don't know why because I've never else used something like margin-top or paddin-top etc...

I just want the two backgrounds to touch eachother

Comment: Which two backgrounds? You've only provided 1 CSS rule, and no HTML markup

Comment: does your background tile correctly?

Comment: Which two background? Is the space maybe in your picture?

Comment: I don't see where is your second background defined

Comment: Is there a white border in the image itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is an incomplete question or its incoherent..  But add repeat after backround.to make it repeat the full length of a div.. If thats what youre asking.

Background: url() repeat;

Comment: `background-repeat: repeat` is a default option, so you don't need to specify

Comment: Well that's cool and true but his code and my code was background: hence requiring a repeat specification.

Comment: @MichaelO'Brien - `background` is a shorthand property that encompasses color, image, repeat, top, left, size, cover, clip, and a few other things. Defining `background` is the same as defining all these other ones, and anything you leave off of background uses defaults. [See the spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/)

Answer (score 0):

probably `html, body {
margin: 0;
}`